# Stop YouTube Playlist Autoplaying to Unrelated Videos

Tags: youtube, autoplay

For some reason, when I reach the end of my YouTube music playlist, instead of just stopping, it autoplays to a completely unrelated video that isn't in the playlist. I don't known when this started, but it's really inconvenient, firstly because it subjects me to random songs I didn't put in my list, and secondly because it also links me away from the playlist, so I have to reload the entire thing.

Is there any way I can make this stop? I just want my playlists to stop when they reach the end, instead of linking me to random videos. Autoplay in the video itself is off.